# CS50 Week 2: Converting vowels to numbers and outputting new string

Tags: beginner, c

Problem: User inputs a word or phrase as command-line argument and a new word is printed with some vowels replaced by numbers.

Question: How do I improve my code design and style? Is it possible to not have to repeat `x[i] == '…'` in my `if` statement?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

string replace(string x);
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) // if user does not input 2 words, then print 'ERROR' message
    {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        replace(argv[1]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

string replace(string x)
{
    for(int i = 0, c = strlen(x); i < c; i++) //for each character 'i', do the following until the position of character is less than the length of the string
    {
        if (x[i] == 'a' || x[i] == 'e' || x[i] == 'i' || x[i] == 'o')
                {
                    switch (x[i])
                    {
                        case 'a':
                            printf("6");
                            break;
                        case 'e':
                            printf("3");
                            break;
                        case 'i':
                            printf("1");
                            break;
                        case 'o':
                            printf("0");
                            break;
                        default:
                            printf("%s\n", x);
                    }
                }
            else //if not a vowel as above, print same character
                {
                    printf("%c", x[i]);
                }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need to forward-declare `replace()` if we define it before `main()`.  That saves having to keep the two signatures maintained in parallel.  As a general guide, put `main()` last in your program, and the lowest-level functions first.

---

We can improve the error handling:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

```
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

---

`replace()` returns a string but we don't use that.  I would expect something like

```
        printf("%s\n", replace(argv[1]));
```

Because the `replace()` function has two responsibilities (transforming the input and printing it), it's less reusable than a function that just does one thing.

---

We have a type mismatch in `int c = strlen(x)`.  The function returns a `size_t`, so we should make `c` the same type.  Instead of using `strlen()`, consider using a pointer that advances until it reaches a null character.

---

We don't need `if`/`else` around the `switch`.  Use the `default:` label for the non-matching letters.

---

## Modified code

Applying my improvements (and using ordinary `char*` instead of CS50 `string`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *replace(char *const s)
{
    for (char *p = s;  *p;  ++p) {
        switch (*p) {
        case 'a':
            *p = '6';
            break;
        case 'e':
            *p = '3';
            break;
        case 'i':
            *p = '1';
            break;
        case 'o':
            *p = '0';
            break;
            /* default: no change */
        }
    }
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", replace(argv[1]));
    }
}
```